# On Newman's proof of Tauberian theorem in PNT

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory

So I have come across the proof of Prime Number Theorem by Newman. I do understand the most part but except for the part in which Newman proves Tauberian's theorem. I have two current questions for the theorem and the proof.
The first question is that what does it mean by extend holomorphically for $\displaystyle G(z) = \int_{0}^{\infty}F(t) e^{-zt} \mathrm{d}t$ where $F(t)$ is bounded and locally integrable ? Cause from what I have learned in $\textbf{Complex Analysis}$, the meaning would be equivalent to analytic continuation, wouldn't it?

The second question is referring to the proof of the theorem, so Newman considered the contour which is the boundary of the region $D_R = \{z \in \mathbb{C} | \Re{(z)} \geq - \delta, \vert z \vert \leq R \}$ in which $\delta > 0$ is an arbitrary small number. My inquiry is that how can he consider such $\delta$ exists for any functions under the above restrictions? Cause if one takes $F(t) = 1$ then $G(z)$ will not converge, won't it?
I'm a self-learner, if there are any misconceptions, hope you all can point them out. Thank you very much.

Comment: Something is messed up with the variables $t$ and $z$ in your formula for $G$. You also have $x$ later on. Can you clarify these and use the least number of variables necessary? The words *holomorphic* and *analytic* are interchangeable.

Comment: Fixed. My apology.

Comment: I think it is assumed that $G(z)$ can be extended analitically to a neighbourhood of the imaginary axis. This of course has certain consequences on $F$ as well. For example the integral of $F$ exists on $(0,\infty)$ and equals $G(0)$.

Comment: So I want to carify more on the first question which is if this is refered to analytic continuation, what can we derive from this hypothesis to help us prove the theorem?

Comment: You have to follow the proof by Newman to figure that out.

Comment: Yes I do try to follow but I can't see it through for three days...

Comment: Hi sir Garry? Please help me with it? cause as what I asked in the second question, how can he consider such contour because I thought G(z) wouldnt be defined on that contour? may be it's related to the analytic continuation?

Comment: As I said it is assumed that $G$ can be extended analitically to a neighbourhood of the imaginary axis. Thus, for an appropriate $\delta>0$, the function $G$ will be analytic (and defined) along the contour.